# state, meaning "government"

Tags: capitalization

Should "state" be capitalized when it refers to a national government? I am editing documents about censorship written by native Chinese and they frequently use the term "the State" to refer to the Chinese government as a whole. Not sure which way it should be written.

Comment: It's an issue for a style manual.  Consider your audience.  In general, it would not be capitalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introductory comment:  Referring to a style manual just brings the discussion back here:  we're supposed to be presenting proper style;  indeed, we take pride in showing the reason(s) for a style being proper.

To the Question (A rule and an example):  Most of the rules for capitalization I have been taught (or harangued about) propose that, when referring to a specific State (e.g., China), the word "State" acts as if it is a stand-in or place-holder for the name of the State.  Thus, if "China" rates capitalization, then "State" does also.  Where the discussion is about some abstract government, then "state" would be appropriate.